# HttpContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync leaves behind a temporary file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpcontent

I'm starting to go loopy on this one, which normally means I'm missing something obvious.

I have the following code in my .NET MVC controller:

```
var provider = new CustomMultipartFileStreamProvider("prefix", GetRepositoryTempFolder());
await request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

The CustomMultipartFileStreamProvider inherits from MultipartFileStreamProvider, overrides the GetLocalFileName method and returns an appropriate file name for a given ContentDisposition header. The HttpContent handled is normally a PDF file and a small JSON settings component.

Everything works wonderfully as far as getting the parts parsed, extracted and saved in the expected location. However, after parsing I end up with a temporary file left over in my C:\Windows\Temp folder. The file has a randomly generated name (e.g. zf0hk2h4.ks2). It has the same size and creation date as the PDF portion parsed and saved by ReadAsMultipartAsync.

I believe ReadAsMultipartAsync uses this temporary file during parsing and leaves it behind. Has anyone else experienced this? Any way I can prevent ReadAsMultipartAsync from leaving this temporary file behind and clogging up the Windows temp folder?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies; I *was* missing something. The file was being moved after processing. This is an invalid question; there is nothing wrong with ReadAsMultipartAsync.